# UDP video using QMediaplayer library

Tags: c++, qt, udp, multimedia, qmediaplayer

I've been playing around the QMediaplayer library. I was curious about how it would work with some streaming video source, so I've used VLC to stream some videos using udp protocol.

To make a quick test, I've used the Qt example named *MediaPlayer example*. As the example is designed to work only with offline files, I've added on dumb function on the Player implementation.

```
void setM(QUrl url){player->setMedia(url);player->play();}
```

Then, on the **main.cpp** file I call this function like this:

```
...
player.setM(QUrl("udp://239.1.1.1:1234"));
return app.exec();
```

What this do is start to reproducing the stream source once the program is read.

The problem here is that Qt through me the following error:

```
 DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 800c000d
```

To do this with local files and **http streaming** and it works... but when I tried with UDP or RTP I always get the same error.

I've spent few hours looking for more information, but always get the same response... use QMLVLC... For example, [look this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/37370/qml-video-play-rtsp-stream-unresolved-error-code).

Does anyone tried this before? What's is wrong here?

PD: I know that there is a VLC plugging to make this work, but I would like make this work only with Qt (or at least, understand what is happening here).

PD2: I'm on windows 8.1, Qt 5.5 (mingw 4.9.2) and I have all the important codecs installed.

Thanks in advance,

**UPDATE**

Finally, I manage to deal with the new http://code.qt.io and here is the code I suspect is blocking udp (and others) protocols-> [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmultimedia.git/tree/src/plugins/directshow/player/directshowplayerservice.cpp).
Maybe, only "http" and "https" are accepted as valid stream sources on Directshowsservice... I'll try to get some extra time this week to recompile just the multimedia module for windows in order to add udp procotol to the function doSetUrlSource and see what happens. If anyone test it first, please let me know here!

**UPDATE 2**

First of all, I suspect QMediaPlayer couldn't reproduce UDP/RTP content because the AddFilter method... Anyway, http,https and rtsp works perfectly.

Secondly, I've found some strange behavior over udp protocol.
I'm using "udp://@239.1.1.1:1234" as test multicast direction. The strange thing is that during one test I put this direction by mistake "udp://@239.1.1.1:1234z" and this time no error has been through. It seems that the direction needs to contain a letter.

Comment: You need a debug build of Qt. Set brekpoints on all lines that emit this error message. Go from there.

Comment: Do you mean to check where qt is complaining?
I used to make I quick check on qt code using gitorius... but since they moved to http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt it's a thug task.
Anyway, I will try to find where the DirectShowPlayerService asserts are placed on?

Comment: If you're serious about Qt, you should be using your own build anyway. So just download a release tarball/zip, `configure -debug-and-release`, use grep or Qt Creator's find-in-files to find that error message, set the breakpoints, fire up your project under debugger, and it should stop inside of Qt source code that issues these error. Yes, you need to check where Qt is complaining. If you will be changing the code to fix a bug, if there is one, you definitely need a git checkout of relevant modules to track your own changes.

Comment: You should use current code, shipped in a release that you actually use. Why do you refer to some "old" code?

Comment: Thanks! Definitely, I need to give it a try. I have done this a hundred of time on Linux... Let's see how I do it on Windows.